.NET 8 SignedXml conflict with AOT ahead of time IL2026 requires dynamic code attirbute
I develop .net8 desktop on window10, we have already developed a license generator earlier, and we have module in app to load licene.lic and check if valid.
after upgraded in .net8 and we want to use Native AOT deployment,
there shows error: Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  IL3050  https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/warnings/il3050
"using member system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml which has requeresDynamicCodeAttribute, can break functionality when AOT compiling, xmlDsigXsltTransform uses XslCompiledTransform which requires dynamic code."
the verifyhash or verifydata always returns false.
how to solve it? is there any other technology to achieve validating the current license.lic?
Thanks!
i have tried to implement with:
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.LoadXml(nodeList[0].OuterXml);

 XmlNode signedInfoNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ds:SignedInfo", GetNamespaceManager(xmlDoc));
 string signedInfoXml = signedInfoNode.OuterXml;

 XmlNode signatureNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ds:SignatureValue", GetNamespaceManager(xmlDoc));

    using (SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create())
    {
        byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(signedInfoBytes);

        // Get the SignatureValue
        XmlNode signatureValueNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ds:SignatureValue", GetNamespaceManager(xmlDoc));
        byte[] signatureValue = Convert.FromBase64String(signatureValueNode.InnerText);

        // Verify the hash against the SignatureValue using the RSA public key
        bool isValid = key.VerifyHash(hash, signatureValue, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
        var _isvalid2 = key.VerifyData(data: signedInfoBytes, signatureValue, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);


        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
        // System.ComponentModel.License lic = new System.ComponentModel.License();
        // Verify the hash against the SignatureValue using the RSA public key
        // bool isValid2 = key.VerifyHash(hash, signatureValue, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1 );

        // var _test = SignedXml.CheckSignature(key, true);
        if (isValid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Signature is valid.");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Signature is invalid.");
            return false;
        }
    }

